# iOS & Swift: ViewController class is defined, but when is it created as an object?

Tags: swift, class, object, viewcontroller

Learning Swift as my first new language in many years, I've come across something I'm curious about using Xcode and creating a new iOS project using the single view template.

In the default ViewController.swift file, UIkit is imported, and then the class ViewController is defined, inheriting from UIViewController. But I can't seem to find out *where* or *how* this class is ever created or initialized as an object.

[Default ViewController.swift example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmIcx.png)

If I define my own class, or even want to create another view controller, I must first initialize it as an object somewhere in order to use it. *So where is this default ViewController getting made?*

Thanks for any help you can offer for me to try to conceptualize this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your "Main.storyboard" file. Make sure `View Controller` is selected on the left sidebar:

[image]

Then on the right sidebar you can see that your `ViewController` class is in the class field:

[image]

So, when your app is loaded, the default storyboard is loaded, and that storyboard is responsible for creating an instance of the `ViewController` class and set it up for you. To test this out, you could create a new class, say `ViewController2` and make it inherit from `UIViewController`. `ViewController2` would then be available in the right sidebar:

[image]

And then your `ViewController2` code will be used instead of `ViewController`.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you @squill25!

Comment: @Evan Pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the location of the ViewControllerQuestion.app file

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the **UIApplicationDelegate** takes care of the creation of the initial view controller. You still can manually create view controllers as you mentioned and segue to them.

Normally you can create a view controller in a storyboard and use the Interface Builder to set up a segue to that view controller.

I hope this answers your question.